# Non-exhaustive patterns with syntactic sugar and pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I wrote the function `fun1` which takes a list and drops every number that is bigger or equal than the previous numbers.

```hs
fun1 (l:ls) =
    fun' [l] ls
  where
    fun' a z =
      case z of
        []  -> a
        _   -> fun' (if (head z) < (last a) then a ++ [head z] else a) (tail z)
```

That works just fine:

```hs
> fun1 [4,4,5,9,7,4,3,1,2,0]
=> [4,3,1,0]
```

In the last line instead of using `head z` and `tail z` I want to use `z@(x:xs)` which is a syntactic sugar I've seen once.

I tried it in `fun2`, but there I get an Non-exhaustive patterns error.
When I use `case xs of` instead `case z of` the function runs without throwing an error, but that way it will either skip the last element or I will have to write the operation to apply to the last element again (which I obviously don't want to do).

```hs
fun2 (l:ls) =
    fun' [l] ls
  where
    fun' a z@(x:xs) =
      case z of -- "case xs of" would work, but will skip the last element
        []  -> a
        _   -> fun' (if x < (last a) then a ++ [x] else a) xs
```

This results in an Non-exhaustive patterns error:

```hs
> fun2 [4,4,5,9,7,4,3,1,2,0]
*** Exception: main.hs:(4,5)-(7,61): Non-exhaustive patterns in function fun'
```

Why do I get this error when I try to match the pattern of `z`?

Comment: `fun1` is not defined for non-empty lists (nor is `fun2`.

Comment: That's true, but assuming one will only call `fun1` and `fun2` with non empty lists still the problem lies in `fun' `, or did I miss something? Of course I could add `fun1 [] = []`, but that won't resolve my problem.

Comment: The same for `fun'`: you only defined this if the second parameter is non-empty, so the `case z` makes no sense: you pattern match on `(x:xs)`

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem! How could I not see that! :D

Comment: So basically when having an argument like `z@(x:xs)` it behaves more or less like an argument `(x:xs)` which is additionally accessible via `z` and NOT the other way around (as I thought)? In other words: `@(x:xs)` only works for e.g. lists that have at least one element.

Comment: yes: the pattern will "fire" if all subpatterns match as well.

Comment: Using `last` and `++ [foo]` repeatedly like this is expensive. Just start emitting values directly instead, as in `fun1 (l:ls) = fun' l ls where fun' a [] = []; fun' a (x:xs) = if x < a then x : fun' x xs else fun' a xs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression:

```
fun' a z@(x:xs)> =
    case z of -- "case xs of" would work, but will skip the last element
        []  -> a
        _   -> fun' (if x < (last a) then a ++ [x] else a) xs
```

makes not much sense, it means that the clause will only "fire" if `z` is a non-empty list, so the case `[] -> …` will never fire, since the pattern `(x:xs)` already restricts the clause to non-empty lists.

You thus can rewrite this to:

```
fun' a z =
    case z of
        []     -> a
        (x:xs) -> fun' (if x < (last a) then a ++ [x] else a) xs
```

For the given sample input, this returns:

```
Prelude> fun2 [4,4,5,9,7,4,3,1,2,0]
[4,3,1,0]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was to focused on using this syntactic sugar `@(x:xs)` so I was completely blinded. First I defined a second `fun' a [] = a` but your solution is of course much cleaner!